# String to Same Byte Array

Tags: c#, string, arrays

How can I convert a string like this

```
string s = "00-11-22-33-44-55-66-77-88-99-00-11-22-3A-4A-5A";
```

to a byte array like this

```
byte[] b = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0x00, 0x11, 0x22, 0x3A, 0x4A, 0x5A };
```

Comment: What language is this? And what you have tried?

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s
.Split('-')
.Select(part => byte.Parse(part, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber))
.ToArray();
```

Comment: Linq always wins in my book! :)

Comment: It is `HexNumber`, not `Hex`.

Answer (score 0):

First off, remove all dashes from your string.

```
string str = "00-11-22-33-44-55-66-77-88-99-00-11-22-3A-4A-5A";

// remove all except hex compliant chars
Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-fA-F0-9]");  

// now do the stripping
str = rgx.Replace(str, "");
```

> Better stripping and checking if the string is actually hex can be implemented here but for this lets keep it simple.

Then use this function

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex) {
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                     .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                     .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                     .ToArray();
}
```

Then

```
// actually do the converting
StringToByteArray(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string s = "00-11-22-33-44-55-66-77-88-99-00-11-22-3A-4A-5A";
var strArray = s.Split('-');
var byteArr = (from item in strArray
              select Byte.Parse(item, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

Do following steps: Parse all of the string using '-' character and output all of the substrings in an string array, than,  add "Ox" at the beginning of all strings in array.
Codes below can easily solve your problem in c#.

Comment: They are still strings then... Not a byte array